# Fill screen with height

Tags: html, css, height

I want my page to fill the screen even if it doesn't contain enough content. I have made this happen with height set to 100% in body. What I also want is some space around my content, and by adding 5px to the margin it gets how I want it. My problem is that then I have to scroll to see the whole page, even if the content is not too long for the screen. I guess there is a simple sollution to this, but I can't seem to find it. Anyone who can?

```css
/* Allmänt */

html, body{
background: grey;
background-size: cover;
height: 100%;
}

#content{
background-color: white;
width: 1100px;
margin: 5px auto;
border-radius: 5px;
position: relative;
height: auto !important;
min-height: 100%;
}

/* Header */

#huvud{
width: 1000px;
height: 250px;
margin: 0 auto;
position: relative;
padding-top: 5px;
}

#header{
display: block;
}

/* Meny */

#nav-yttre{
width: 1000px;
height: 35px;
margin: 0 auto;
background-image: url("Rusty-bar2.jpg");
}

#nav-mitten{
display: table;
width: 100%;
padding: 10px;
}

#nav-inre{
display: table-row;
list-style: none;
font-family: 'Special Elite', Verdana, Arial, sans-serif;
font-size: 25px;
}

#nav-inre li{
display: table-cell;
}

#nav-inre li a{
display: block;
text-decoration: none;
text-align: center;
color: #eeeeee;
}

#nav-inre li #here{
color: #221f20;
}

#nav-inre li a:hover{
color: #221f20;
}

/* Main */

#main{
width: 980px;
margin: 0 auto;
height: 100%;
position: relative;
padding-bottom: 150px;
}

#fadein { 
margin: 10px auto;
position:relative; 
width:970px; 
height:215px; 
padding: 5px;
box-shadow: 0 0 20px rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
}

#fadein img { 
position:absolute; 
}

#main-blogg{
width: 1050px;
margin: 0 auto;
}

#blogg{
min-height: 1000px;
}

/* Fot */

#fot{
width: 980px;
margin: 0 auto;
text-align: center;
}

#fot-inre{
border-top: solid #221f20 1px;
position: absolute;
bottom: 0;

}

#adress{
width: 327px;
float: left;
}

#kontakt{
width: 326px;
float: left;
}

#tider{
width: 326px;
float: right;
}

#design{
width: 500px;
margin: 0 auto;
clear: both;
text-align: center;
background-image: url("Rusty-bar-small.jpg");
}

#design p{
color: #eeeeee;
font-weight: bold;
}

#design a{
color: #eeeeee;
}

#design a:hover{
color: #221f20;
}

#rub{
font-weight: bold;
}

/* Allmänt */

p{
font-family: Verdana, Arial, sans-serif;
color: #221f20;
font-size: 0.9em;
}
```

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" 
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stajlish.css">
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Special+Elite' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<script type="text/javascript" src="stajlish.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

<div id="content">

 <div id="huvud">
  <img id="header" src="hej.jpg" alt="Header">
 </div>
 
 <div id="nav-yttre">
  <div id="nav-mitten">
   <ul id="nav-inre">
    <li><a href="index.html">HEM</a></li>
    <li><a href="om_oss.html">OM OSS</a></li>
    <li><a href="blogg.html">BLOGG</a></li>
    <li><a href="marken.html">M&Auml;RKEN</a></li>  
    <li><a href="hitta_hit.html">HITTA HIT</a></li>
   </ul>
  </div>
 </div>
 
 <div id="main">
 
  <div id="fadein">
   <img src="slides1.jpg">
   <img src="slides2.jpg">
   <img src="slides3.jpg">
  </div>
  
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aliquam tempus quam lectus, in suscipit nisl luctus feugiat. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Praesent elit eros, tempor sed bibendum nec, luctus in dui. Proin vitae tincidunt diam, a pulvinar tortor. Maecenas pulvinar rhoncus nisl quis aliquet. Nulla dolor metus, euismod ac gravida eget, congue at nunc. Etiam non urna vel dolor pulvinar finibus. Suspendisse eget lacinia massa. Morbi sodales non purus pretium congue. Nullam sed tellus diam. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Nulla porta sapien sit amet placerat lobortis. Nunc sed orci tincidunt, lacinia massa ut, fringilla est. Maecenas sodales orci at erat malesuada, non tristique leo auctor. Suspendisse augue felis, lobortis rhoncus pharetra at, pretium sit amet dolor.</p>
  
 </div>
  
 <div id="fot">
 
  <div id="fot-inre">
 
  <div id="adress">
   <p id="rub">BES&Ouml;KSADRESS</p>
   <p>Hej</p>
  </div>
  
  <div id="kontakt">
   <p id="rub">KONTAKTA OSS</p>
   <p>Telefon: 08-123 45 67</p>
   <p>Mail: info@mail.se</p>
  </div>
  
  <div id="tider">
   <p id="rub">&Ouml;PPETTIDER</p>
   <p>Vardagar: 10-19<br>L&ouml;rdag: 10-17<br>S&ouml;ndag: 11-16</p> 
  </div>
  
  <div id="design">
   <p>Webbplatsen &auml;r gjord av Maria</p>
  </div>
  
  </div>

 </div>
 
</div>

</body>
```

Answer (score 2):

Bulletproof full height!

```
*,
*:before,
*:after {
    -webkit-box-sizing:border-box;
    -mozbox-sizing:border-box;
    box-sizing:border-box;
}

html,
body {
    height:100%;
    height:100vh;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}

#content {
    height:auto !important;
    min-height:100%;
    min-height:100vh;
}
```

Reasons:

- `100vh` is supported in IE9 and above (and basically anything else), and `100%` is used as a fallback
- `border-box` is a key piece of layout functionality, to support recalc after padding (so `width:50px` actually remains `50px`, instead of `50px` plus padding), and it works back to IE8
- adding the `margin:0;padding:0;` to the `html,body` eliminates the white space around it ... if you desperately want padding on the `body`, add it separately (although you should really have it on whatever container you have for everything)

**EDIT**

So the reason you are still needing to scroll is because `border-box` handles `padding`, but not `margin`. If you want "room" around your content, add the padding there:

```
#content {
    height:auto !important;
    min-height:100%;
    min-height:100vh;
    padding:5px 0;
}
```

This will give you the effect of room on top and bottom. However, if (for some crazy reason) you are really clinging to the need for `margin` over `padding`, you could use `calc`:

```
#content {
    height:auto !important;
    min-height:calc(100% - 10px);
    min-height:calc(100vh - 10px);
    margin:5px auto;
}
```

Only supported on IE9 and up, but will give you what you are looking for. I **highly** advise against it though, as what you are trying to attain is much more easily doable in ways that don't involve `margin`.

Comment: I don't see any difference with this code, still the same problem.

Comment: @maraki - I added the `margin:0;padding:0;` piece, that should help.

Comment: What happens here is that it fits in the screen, but I don't get any space on top/bottom of content that I want.

Comment: edited my answer to include a couple of options, but it is borne out of your use of `margin` on `#content`. my recommendation is to try to find a different way (such as `padding` instead), because the way you are doing it severely limits your chances of achieving the goal you have.

Comment: Of course I don't need to use margin, that was just my first (obviously stupid) try to solve the problem. But padding doesn't seem to give me the space I want, not even when I do excactly like you say. So weird... I think I'll reconsider the need of space. Maybe I can live without it... thanks anyway!

Answer (score 1):

I would implement 2 things. I would use a bumper and calc.

```
<div class="bumper"></div>

.bumper {
    height:5px;
    width:100%;
}
```

put the bumper where you would want your padding to be. Then use calc to set the height of the content.

```
#content {
    background-color: white;
    max-width:800px;
    padding: 5px;
    min-height:90%; //backup for browsers who do not support calc
    min-height:calc(100% -5px);
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    border-radius: 5px;
}
html, body {
    background: grey;
    height: 100%;
    margin:0px; //important
}
```

Result:
http://jsfiddle.net/m/qes/

Full Code: http://jsfiddle.net/neoaptt/r2ddyg8e/

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
html, body{
background: grey;
background-size: cover;
height: 100%;
}
```

to

```
html, body{
background: grey;
background-size: cover;
height: 100vh;
}
```

then add a reset

```
*{box-sizing: border-box; padding: 0; margin: 0}
```

you can read more about [Sizing with CSS3's vw and vh units](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/length)

Comment: This doesn't change anything for me. It fits everything inside the screen, but remove the space around the content.

Answer (score 0):

The problem:
The reason you have to scroll to see the whole page is because you are giving your element with the id content a min-height of 100% and then also giving it a margin of 5px auto. This is essentially saying I want my content element to have a height of 100% + 5px on the top and 5px on the bottom of margin. height now equals: (100% + 10px).

The answer:
If you want space around your content use the padding property on your content element instead of the margin. This will push the elements within the content element inward 5px from the top and 5px from the bottom, without increasing the height of your content element past 100%.

It should look something like this (not tested):

```
#content{
background-color: white;
width: 1100px;
padding: 5px auto; /* changed margin to padding */
border-radius: 5px;
position: relative;
height: auto !important;
min-height: 100%;
}
```

Comment: I thought this would work, I get the logic, but it still doesn't change anything.

Answer (score 0):

You have a top and bottom margin on your `#content` div. Remove it and add this to the `body` :

```
body {
    padding: 5px 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```